# Display one by one text in textview every 10 seconds

Tags: android, database, textview

I want to display one by one some text which is named A,B,C,D in textview every 10 seconds (A-B-C-D-A-B-C-D...).
Can everyone give me some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeking for code without any try is no a good habit. Anyways I am giving you a hint, try ureself. There are several other options. Here are some

**Option 1:**

put the texts in a array of string, use a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to show the text one by one from the array every 10 seconds. when you reach the end of the array again show the first text.

**Option 2:**

as FoamyGuy suggeted. use [TextView.postDelayed][2] method to perform your task. In the runnable in postDelayed use the postDelayed method call recursively.

**Option 3:**

use different thread to perform your time counting then when triggered show the text using [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

So from these options (and may be other options too) I think it is better for you to learn and choose  your option.

[2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

Comment: there is no need to use Timer object. View, and thus TextView has a `postDelayed()` method that you can use to post a runnable that will change the text.

Comment: yup there can be several other solutions. yes you are righ use postdelayed will be a good choice

Comment: Sory about seeking for code without any try. I'm new to android so i have not an idea to do that. I tried to find some code in google but...